# Spyder Multiprocessing error: Cannot get attribute(function)

Tags: python, spyder, python-multiprocessing

I've been trying to use map functions with multiprocessing in python. Works just fine on IDLE, but spyder has been making it absolutely impossible.

The 'Cannot get attribute....' error pops up because I've not included () after calling my function.
E.g. sp=imap(subProcess,List) raises the error, But sp=imap(subProcess(),List) does not.

The trouble is now, It's impossible to pass in arguments through the map function, and it can only be done by passing in arguments through subProcess(argument), making any kind of map function USELESS. Simply leaving the subProcess arguments blank raises an error message saying that 1 arguments expected but 0 were given.

The only other way around I  can think of is simply just using some for loops with the Process function to mimic the map function, but must I really resort to that?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Downvoting as the question doesn't show any research effort. Consider searching for similar problems before asking.

Comment: Tried running it in an external terminal, saving the subprocess as a new module and importing it, tried using other map functions or other functions within multi-processing that would serve the same purpose as map, tried using concurrent futures instead, tried re-writing everything in expressions that might allow my to pass arguments in by other means. None of it worked, and none of the other posts I found really pin-pointed it to being a syntax error that was related to the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Spyder uses an interactive python console which is incompatible with Multiprocessing. One workaround to this is to use the Spyder-terminal plugin to run a system shell instead of the default ipython console, the install instructions for which can be found [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/plugins/terminal.html). Or you will simple have to run your code from another terminal or IDE